# Alternative to headless browser on pdf generation of GCharts

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf, phantomjs

Does anyone know of an alternative to phantomjs to render some GCharts in pdf?

We are currently using phantomjs but the speed of it is to slow.

Answer (score 1):

All the alternatives (casperJS, slimerJS, wkhtmltopdf... See a list here https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) will be almost the same... You have to instantiate a browser, takes several seconds. 
You have PhantomjsCloud that is pretty fast, takes for me 3-4 seconds for generating a pdf from an html page...

The faster solution will be a native asp.net library, such Select.Pdf : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.Pdf/

This sample code can help you (uses gchart+asp.net for generating pff) : https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/web-applications/create-html-5-charts-export-them-pdf-free

Comment: Just to knowi did the PDF library and sample code help you ?